# How to change resolution of LCD for ps3 slim

Tags: ps3

I have a PS3 slim. Whenever I connect it to my LCD with HDMI cable, it shows no signal. How can I get a signal? My LCD shows its resolution at 1920. I reset my PS3 display by holding power button for 5/10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have incompatible video settings with your screen. I remember that I have a similar problem and I had to connect PS3 with the previous TV (via SCART) and go through the video settings wizard to set options corresponding with my new LCD TV (HDMI).